# Multi-Store with option for user to create store

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

I search for next option:

We want to develop main site, who give the option to his users (who registerd) to open sub-stores under our main store.

I saw the option of multi-store on Magento,Shopify, Opencart, Wordpress and so… but i dont sure if it answer my question.

If there is somthing that do what we serach – i will be happy if there is also ready theme for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Magento Has good potential of that TO create a multiple website, store and language. You definitely choose this platform.

hear are two extension as per your requirement like multi-vendor.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/umarketplace-suite-8485.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/super-simple-multi-vendor-marketplace-free-2295.html